# What experience do gem dragons give off?

Tags: dragonvale

I've been trying to get a gem dragon, and I'm not sure how many gems a month they give.

Does anyone know?

Comment: _sorry I forgot to put dragonvale_

Comment: I am not sure if you are asking if when you get a gem do you get experience as well or just how often do you get gems?

Comment: No @james , I'm talking about the gem dragon not the gems.

Answer (score 1):

Gem dragons usually at level 10 give 1/week